# ASP.NET Core 3 with Angular 8, ASP.NET Core Identity, Roles and token based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, bearer-token

Problem:
Creating a WebApi that is secured with a token passed from api client.
Some api methods should be available only to users with certain roles defined.
E.g.

The scenario would look like this:
Angular8 calls WebApi to login

```js
httpClient.Post(new LogInRequest(userName, password));
```

WebApi signs in the user and generates token

```cs
signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password);
var token = GenerateToken(userName); // token should be generated internally
return token;
```

Angular8 calls WebApi and includes in header the token

```js
httpClient.Post(header: "TOKEN", new CreateCompanyRequest(company));
```

Now the WebApi checks if the user assigned to token is allowed to perform this action

```cs
[Authorize("Supervisor")] // only user with Supervisor role should be able to use this controller
public class CompanyController : Controller
```

Above code is just a sample how I would see it working. So far I've tried reading some JWT Bearer explanation but most of these articles were from old version of asp.net.
If you could explain to me how this authentication should work, or point me to some documentation on how to combine asp.net core identity with webapi token authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to below link which introduce to you a complete sample to use asp.net core Identity authentication ,JWT token authorization in asp.net core web api:

https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

You could just adapt its [source code](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth) to asp.net core 3.0 with 3.0 packages and it will work.

Comment: That looks **exactly** like what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: What if I created project .net core 3.0 with angular 8 and Individual user account and there is already authentication? Authorization without role wokrs but how can I update this to work with role? In token in angular side that I get from api I dont have role. Only user id